# How to migrate SQL Server DB with synonym to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a SQL Server DB on-prem, lets call it xDB
I also have number of services that query the DB

now, I need to migrate xDB to Azure Paas without changing the code in the services (including connection string to the DBs)

I thought to migrate xDB to Azure and keep the on-prem xDB empty with only Synonyms to Azure xDB

does anyone know if it's possible, and if so, how to reference Synonym from on-prem to Azure SQL PaaS?

Comment: Which dbms are you migrating from?

Comment: SQL Server on VM on-prem